# Solving a pair of dual integral equations

Tags: integration, special-functions, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions, integral-equations

I have the equations

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty dk \ A(k)k \sinh(ka)\cos(kx)=0 \ \ ; \ \ 1<|x|<\infty  \tag{1}
$$
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty dk \  A(k) \cosh(ka) \cos(kx)=1  \ \ ; \ \ |x|<1 \tag{2}
$$

Where $A(k)$ is unknown, $a$ is a real positive constant, and we expect $A=A(k,a)$. I think the general idea is to write

$$
\left[ A(k) \times \operatorname{convenient stuff}(k)\right]=\int\limits_0^1dx' \ g(x') \cos(kx') \tag{*}
$$

Where $g$ is the new unknown, and (*) is chosen such that (1) is satisfied, then substitute this into (2) so that the integral over $k$ may be performed.

**Question in brief:** *What substitution in (*) will allow me to make progress? Or is there a different 'trick' here altogether? Maybe an expansion on the right in something other than cosines?*

The rest of this post is background, and my current attempt.

In **a similar problem**

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty dk \ A(k) k \sin(kx) =0 \ \ ; \ \ 1<|x|<\infty \tag{3}
$$

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty dk \ A(k) \tanh(ka)\sin(kx)=1 \ \ ; \ \ |x|<1 \tag{4}
$$

Setting

$$
A(k) k = \int\limits_0^1 dx' \ g(x') \sin(kx')
$$

Allows one to make progress by substituting into (4), and even (eventually) obtain $g$ analytically. I have tried the similar substitution

$$
A(k) k \sinh(ak)=\int\limits_0^1 dx' g(x') \cos(kx')
$$

So that (1) is satisfied, but substituting this into (2) is not fruitful (divergent integral over $k$).

It is possible that the Fourier expansion in $\cos$ on the RHS of (*) is not the way to go here. Maybe expanding in Bessel functions or something else; but I don't have the intuition to 'see' what is a good expansion. For example, in a (different) similar problem, a useful expansion is

$$
\left[ A(k) \times \operatorname{convenient stuff}(k)\right]=\int\limits_0^1dx' \ g(x') J_0(kx')
$$

Where $J_0$ is a Bessel function of the first kind. The similar problems mentioned above are from: *Mixed boundary value problems* by Dean G. Duffy.

**Current progress**

By integrating (1) and (2) w.r.t. $x$ we obtain

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty dk \ A(k) \sinh(ka)\sin(kx)=0 \ \ ; \ \ 1<|x|<\infty  \tag{1a}
$$
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty dk \  A(k) k^{-1} \cosh(ka) \sin(kx)=x  \ \ ; \ \ |x|<1 \tag{2a}
$$

With the ansatz

$$
A(k) \cosh(ka) = \int\limits_0^1 dx' \ g(x') \sin(kx') \tag{**}
$$

After substituting (**) into (2a), and some algebra, we find

$$
A(k) \cosh(ka) = J_1(k)
$$

However, to justify this we must show it satisfies (1a)

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty dk \ \int\limits_0^1 dx' \ g(x') \sin(kx') \sin(kx) \tanh(ka) \stackrel{?}{=}0 \ \ ; \ \ 1<|x|<\infty  \tag{1b}
$$

Within the integral, we always have $x \neq x'$, so it would be nice to say (distributionally) this is true, but I'm not sure that it is. <s>**Alternative question:** *is (1b) true?*</s>

**Update:** Numerically integrating (1b) shows that it's not true.

Comment: If you differentiate your second integral equation with respect to $a$, then you obtain your first integral equation (at least for $|x|<1$). So it seems like the first integral equation may simply be a consequence of the second.

Comment: @Semiclassical The trouble is that $A$ is expected to depend on $a$. My bad: I've edited my post to make this clear

Comment: Near as I can guess this arises from dealing with Laplace's equation in the region $(-\infty < x < \infty) \times (0 < y < a)$ with $u_y(x, 0) = 0$, $u_y(x, a) = 0$ for $\vert x\vert < 1$, and $u(x, a) = 0$ for $\vert x\vert < 1$. I think this is a form of Riemann-Hilbert problem. It'll be interesting to explore it more if that's the case.